# Can I use a before insert/update trigger in MySQL to cast an empty string to an integer?

Tags: mysql, triggers

MySQL is running in strict mode.  A 3rd party program is generating SQL that I have no access to modify.  The data is... not clean.  There is a field in their data that should be an integer but in many cases is an empty string ('').

Is it possible in MySQL 8 to fix this with a before trigger?  Since I cannot modify the external code my only other option would be to change the SQL_MODE.

Unfortunately my testing seems to indicate that MySQL throws the error "`*1366 - Incorrect integer value: '' for column*`" before the trigger fires, but I may be doing it wrong.

Comment: Post  your schema, code, sample data, and the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

The trigger can't refer to the syntax the client used. It can only  access `NEW.<column_name>`, which has the integer type. So the string `''` has to convert to an integer *before* your trigger starts executing.

What is causing the error in your case is [strict mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict). In strict mode, a string like `''` in an integer context is an error. In non-strict mode, it converts to the implicit default value for the integer type, which is 0. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html#data-type-defaults-implicit

So you have these options:

- Change the code of the client. But you said you have no access to do this.
- Disable strict mode. If you could change the client code, you could set a session mode, but since you can't do that, you have to set it globally. This is unfortunate, because I generally recommend to keep strict mode enabled so it can prevent malformed data.
- Change the data type of the column to a string, so it permits `''`. You can then write a trigger to set the column to the string `'0'` when it sees the empty string. Storing numbers as strings may have other consequences, like if you want to use inequalities to search or you want to sort by the column, it will sort alphabetically instead of by numeric value.
- Experiment with the [query rewrite plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/rewriter-query-rewrite-plugin.html). But I wouldn't choose this solution. It's probably more difficult work to develop and maintain a query rewriter for this case than any of the above options.

None of these solutions are elegant, but I understand you have to get it working.

Regardless, I'd also recommend reporting a bug to the vendor who makes that 3rd party software. They should not be assuming or requiring non-strict mode in MySQL.

Comment: Looking at my code I have decided that the best solution is to change the column in the database to a varchar and modify my code to cast the varchar to an int.